# How to find $n$th term of two sequences both dependent on each other?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given two sequences ,
$$\large a_{n+1}+b_{n+1}=2\sqrt{2}(a_{n})+2\sqrt{6}(b_{n})$$
$$\large a_{n+1}-b_{n+1}=2\sqrt{2}(b_{n})-2\sqrt{6}(a_{n})$$
Given $\large a_{0}$ and $\large b_{0}$ , How can i find $\large a_{n}$ and $\large b_{n}$ separately?

Comment: Try to put them in a array form. Then express $a_n$ and $b_n$ in function of $a_0$ and $b_0$ by using powers of arrays. Maybe they can be diagonalized, and you can obtain a nice equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: the linear system
$$
\left[\matrix{1 & 1\\1 & -1}\right]\left[\matrix{a_{n+1}\\b_{n+1}}\right]=
\left[\matrix{2\sqrt{2} & 2\sqrt{6}\\-2\sqrt{6} & 2\sqrt{2}}\right]\left[\matrix{a_{n}\\b_{n}}\right]\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad\\
\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad
\left[\matrix{a_{n+1}\\b_{n+1}}\right]=\underbrace{\left[\matrix{1 & 1\\1 & -1}\right]^{-1}
\left[\matrix{2\sqrt{2} & 2\sqrt{6}\\-2\sqrt{6} & 2\sqrt{2}}\right]}_{A}\left[\matrix{a_{n}\\b_{n}}\right]
$$
has the solution
$$
\left[\matrix{a_{n}\\b_{n}}\right]=A^n\left[\matrix{a_{0}\\b_{0}}\right].
$$

Comment: Maybe you can diagonalize $A$, and obtain a nice equation.